# Dynamic dropdown, $_GET with spaces

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created a dynamic drop down menu using Javascript/jquery and i populate with php mysql:

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $(this).val());
    });
```

It works perfectly fine, except when the first selected option has two words instead of one (space in-between) Ex: "Option" works fine and second list populates, "Option Two" does not work and second list is blank. Here is my getter.php code:

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT code FROM sets WHERE name='$choice'");
$sth->execute();
$choicecode = $sth->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: `$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT code FROM sets WHERE name='$choice'");`? Please don’t do that. `$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT code FROM sets WHERE name = :choice'); $sth->execute([':choice' => $choice]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces need to be encoded when put in query strings. jQuery can do this for you:

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $.get("getter.php", { choice: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        $("#second-choice").html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode it when you send it in JS:

```
encodeURIComponent($(this).val()); // will produce something like "Option%20Two"
```

So, it should look something like this:

```
(`$("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()) );`)
```

Comment: Fairly sure, yes. See [Notes](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).